# How to do a running calculation across vectors in R?

Tags: r

I created this data frame:

```
Count <- c(1:10)
Give <- c(0,0,5,0,0,5,0,5,0,5)
X <- c(rep(0,10))
Y <- c(rep(0,10))
Z <- c(rep(0,10))

X_Target <- 5
Y_Target <- 10
Z_Target <- 5
```

Basically I have 3 vectors (X,Y,Z) and a target for each one of them.
I want to have a new calculation for X,Y and Z that based on the vector Give.
Once the number on Give is bigger than 0 then it's need to be added to Vector X until it equel to X_Target. Then - the calcultion need to move to the next vector (Y) and do the same, and then to next vector...

The output should be like the following:

```
   Count Give X Y  Z
     1    0   0 0  0
     2    0   0 0  0
     3    5   5 0  0
     4    0   5 0  0
     5    0   5 0  0
     6    5   5 5  0
     7    0   5 5  0
     8    5   5 10 0
     9    0   5 10 0
    10    5   5 10 5
```

In this example I have only 3 vectors but please keep in mind that I'll have at least 60 vectors so I need it to be automatic as it can.

Hope I manage to explain myself :)
Thnanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly, but it gives the desired result.

```
tab1 = data.frame(
  Count = c(1:10),
  Give = c(0,0,5,0,0,5,0,5,0,5),
  X = c(rep(0,10)),
  Y = c(rep(0,10)),
  Z = c(rep(0,10))
)

targets <- c(5,10,5)
tab2 <- tab1
start <- 2

for(col in 3:ncol(tab2)) {
  
  target <- targets[col-2]
  
  
  
  for(row in start:nrow(tab2)) {
    
    if(tab2[row, 2] > 0 & tab2[row, col] < target) {
      tab2[row, col] <- pmin(tab2[row - 1, col] + tab2[row, col - 1], target)
    } else {
      tab2[row, col] <- tab2[row - 1, col]
    }
    
  }
  
  start <- which(tab2[, 2] > 0 & tab2[, col] == target)[2]
}

> tab2
   Count Give X  Y Z
1      1    0 0  0 0
2      2    0 0  0 0
3      3    5 5  0 0
4      4    0 5  0 0
5      5    0 5  0 0
6      6    5 5  5 0
7      7    0 5  5 0
8      8    5 5 10 0
9      9    0 5 10 0
10    10    5 5 10 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a data frame :

```
tab1 = data.frame(
  Count = c(1:10),
  Give =c(0,0,5,0,0,5,0,5,0,5),
  X = c(rep(0,10)),
  Y = c(rep(0,10)),
  Z = c(rep(0,10))
)

# create a list of targets for looping
targets = c(X_Target, Y_Target, Z_Target)
```

Without using data.table you can just put the whole thing in a loop. It will work, but be much slower.

```
# loop through each column
for(col in seq(1,length(targets))){
    print(col)
  
  # loop through each row
  for(row in seq(1, dim(tab1[2+col])[1])){
    
    # condition
    while(tab1[row,(2+col)] < targets[col] & tab1[row,2]>0){
      tab1[row,(2+col)] = tab1[row,(2+col)] +tab1[row,2] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting an error - can you please show me an example with data frame instead of data table? Do I need to create a while loop for each vector? cause I have like 60 of them..

Comment: are all your vectors the same length?

Comment: Yes, all of them are in the same length

Comment: updated for use without data.table, will be much slower, but that might not be to much of an issue if you don't have too much data

Comment: Thanks, it's very close but still not the result that I wish for. The output should be as the example I sent in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

My approach was to make use of the cumulative sums of the `Give` and then track  if that exceeds the targeted values for the columns. Then do some cleaning up.

```
targets <- c(X_Target, Y_Target, Z_Target)
targets_0 <- c(0, targets)
csum_give <- cumsum(Give)

# from cumsum give take off sum of previous targets 
result  <- sapply(1:length(targets), 
            function(x) csum_give - sum(targets_0[1:x]))

# Set max value to target max of column
sapply(1:length(targets), 
    function(x) result[result[, x] > targets[x], x] <<- targets[x])

# set min value to zero
result[which(result < 0)] <- 0


result
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]    0    0    0
#  [2,]    0    0    0
#  [3,]    5    0    0
#  [4,]    5    0    0
#  [5,]    5    0    0
#  [6,]    5    5    0
#  [7,]    5    5    0
#  [8,]    5   10    0
#  [9,]    5   10    0
# [10,]    5   10    5
```

Comment: Thanks, it's super close to the result that I want - just need to show the increasing along the rows - for instance, for vector Y I want that the output will be 5 for rows 5 and 6 (like I showed in my example in the main question)

Comment: Done! I edited the answer, I think this is what you are after

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else to try, using `tidyverse`.

Put your data into long form, and include targets with a join.

In a loop through `Count`, find the first row for a given `Count` that is below target. For current and following rows that have matching names (X, Y, or Z), add `Give` amount.

In the end, put result back into wide form.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(Count, Give, X, Y, Z) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = X:Z) %>%
  left_join(data.frame(X_Target, Y_Target, Z_Target) %>%
              pivot_longer(cols = everything(), 
                           names_to = c("name", ".value"), 
                           names_pattern = "(\\w+)_(\\w+)")) 

for (i in seq_along(Count)) {
  below_target <- min(which(df$Count == i & df$value < df$Target))
  name_rows <- which(df$name == df[below_target, "name", drop = T])
  rows_to_change <- name_rows[name_rows >= below_target]
  df[rows_to_change, "value"] <- df[rows_to_change, "value"] + df[below_target, "Give", drop = T]
}

df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Count)
```

**Output**

```
   Count     X     Y     Z
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     0
 2     2     0     0     0
 3     3     5     0     0
 4     4     5     0     0
 5     5     5     0     0
 6     6     5     5     0
 7     7     5     5     0
 8     8     5    10     0
 9     9     5    10     0
10    10     5    10     5
```